# Unexpected or empty output from tee command

Tags: bash, centos

```sh
echo "hello" | tee test.txt
cat test.txt
sudo sed -e "s|abc|def|g" test.txt | tee test.txt
cat test.txt
```

**Output:**
The output of 2nd command and last command are different, where as the command is same.

**Question:**
The following line in above script gives an output, but why it is not redirected to output file?

```sh
sudo sed -e "s|abc|def|g" test.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo sed -e "s|abc|def|g" test.txt | tee test.txt
```

Reading from and writing to `test.txt` in the same command line is error-prone. `sed` is trying to read from the file at the same time that `tee` wants to truncate it and write to it.

You can use `sed -i` to modify a file *in place*. There's no need for `tee`. (There's also no need for `sudo`. You made the file, no reason to ask for root access to read it.)

```
sed -e "s|abc|def|g" -i test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the same file for both input and output.

`tee test.txt` is emptying the output file when it starts up. If this happens before `sed` reads the file, `sed` will see an empty file. Since you're running `sed` through `sudo`, it's likely to take longer to start up, so this is very likely.